# How to disable Persistence with Chrome Dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, google-chrome-devtools

I was playing around with Chrome DevTools and have set up persistence of my CSS (I'm working with a local copy of a website, running on localhost), but now I would like to switch it off, so that whenever I edit anything in the Elements tab, it wouldn't save the changes automatically. Unfortunately I can't find instructions for disabling it (all I find is either about how to turn this feature on or how to disable cache).

It's a cool feature, but I think it could cause lots of unnecessary style rules that are test left-overs and it would be hard to get rid of them after a while. Sometimes I do quick tests to see how things would look with different styles and I don't want these changes to save and I also don't want to delete them from DevTools manually, I'd rather keep doing it the old way - preview, then copy needed changes to my files manually.

Is there a way to remove file from automatic save on edit? Or is there a way to turn off persistence mode altogether?

Comment: Click Settings icon in devtools and go to Workspaces to edit individual mappings. Not sure it counts as an answer :-)

Comment: I only have the "Folder exclude pattern" setting in there. So it looks like it just adds localhost files by default... I guess adding an exclude rule for my folder could be a way to solve this... But is this how I'm supposed to do this?

Comment: Uh? There's a trashcan icon: https://puu.sh/rxOJK/9038167049.png

Comment: I don't have anything there, other than the exclude pattern input. However, I just tried again and there was a popup asking where to save the changes, I clicked cancel and now it doesn't ask anymore and also doesn't save changes to my file. So the problem is solved, although I'm not quite sure how exactly I did that, because I'm sure I didn't use this tab to delete the folder... Anyway, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

In DevTools, go to the Sources tab, then Right click your website folders that appear there and select "Remove from Workspace".

Refresh website and all the Chrome's behavior will be like before.